# Inject into additive loaded scene in Unity with zenject

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

How can I inject dependencies into an additively loaded scene with zenject?

Answer (score 1):

So here is how it can be done https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject#scene-parenting